# Eloquent: Model relationship without saving to DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have two Models:
User and Task

Their relationship is as follows:
User can have many tasks (belongsToMany) 
Task can have many users (belongsToMany)

```
$user = new User();
$task = new Task();
```

Normally, I'd do something like this:
    `$user->tasks->attach($task)`

But the problem is the User and Task is not persisted in the database. So if I run the last code above, I'll get an integrity constraint because these models have no id.

I have looked into the documentation and I found at that there is a method `associate()` but this requires either one of the model that has an id (saved in the database).

Is there any way I could attach a Model to another Model without them having persisted in the database?

Answer (score 8):

I guess you could call setRelation manually.

```
$model->setRelation('child', $childInstance);
```

eLSE

You create a new model simply by instantiating it:

```
$model = new Model;
```

You can then save it to the database at a later stage:

```
$model->save();
```

Comment: Pass the entire collection when doing hasMany relations.

Comment: $model->setRelation('child', $childInstance); worked for me. And this will return a collection. My use case was to unit test a blade function.

Answer (score -1):

The model in Laravel is nothing but a normal class. So instantiating it only would not persist to DB. You should persist to DB by saving the model:

This can be done by running `save()` as below:

```
$user->save();
$task->save();

$user->tasks()->attach($task->id);
```

It's important to note that the it's `$user->tasks()->attach()` and not `$user->tasks->attach()`

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to save it to the database

Comment: You are using an AR implementation, and you don't want to save to DB? Then what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Technically, I just need the Collection. So you can imagine I could just simply create an array then easily convert it to a Collection. But I type-hint my classes to only accept an instance of 'that' Model so I wouldn't get any runtime exception... And I thought it was smart...

Comment: Why not type-hint as a collection. You can use the Collection class.

Comment: May seems weird, but Im triyng to separe responsabilities (creating models) from saving to database (Im using Eloquent Models as domain entities) and encountered in the same situation. The answer of @Arun Ganessh helped me a lot